# PowerShell win10 - the window does not show English

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have windows 10 64bit in hebrew , and I've installed the powershell but I got this windows without English titles , I've already to try reinstall , but it's doesn't successfuly.

[image]

please help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fine now, I was missing an unicode.

Comment: can you expand what you mean "I was missing an unicode" ?

Comment: yes . my computer was support only on ASCII letter , so I replace it to Unicode letter , you can see this at the site : https://en.softonic.com/articles/how-to-display-unicode-languages-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, that was fixed first with the Update [KB4020102 (OS Build 15063.332)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020102).

> Addressed issue where some non-Unicode fonts (Courier, MS Sans Serif,
>   etc.) do not render characters correctly on non-Latin, single-byte
>   system locales (Greek, Hebrew, Arabic, etc.). Black bars or other
>   artifacts appear instead.

This should [fix your issue, according to a Microsoft employee which replied](https://twitter.com/JenMsft/status/867849971835346944) to an user on twitter who had the issue.

So open Windows Update and install the newest update to fix the issue with the ugly characters.